# Armory3d blender Haxe code keyboard input (single quote)

Tags: input, blender, haxe, quote

I have a question regarding the Haxe code. I try to use the quote as an input but it does not seem to work.

```
if (Input.getKeyboard().down("\'")) {
    trace("TEST");
}
```

however when I use something like

```
if (Input.getKeyboard().down("\\")) {
    trace("TEST");
}
```

When I press the \ button it works.

When I output the single quote as such:

```
var quote="\'";
trace(quote);
```

The output comes out correct as '

If anyone has insight as to why it does not work I would apreciate the help!!!

Thank you!